# GDI+ font issue in Windows 2008 R2 OS

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have installed the "Minion Pro" OTF font in the machine and the font exists in the "C:\Windows\Fonts" folder but unable to create System.Drawing.Font instance for "Minion Pro" font.

Please find the code snippet.

```
        System.Drawing.Font minionPro = new System.Drawing.Font("Minion Pro", 12);
        if(minionPro.Name !=  "Minion Pro")
            minionPro = new System.Drawing.Font("Minion Pro Regular", 12);
```

The above code returns the "Microsoft Sans Serif" the default font in Windows 2008 R2. And in Windows 10 OS, this code returns "Minion Pro" as expected. So this problem occurs specific to Windows 2008 R2.

Can anyone help on this, how to retrieve the fonts properly in Windows 2008 R2? Is there any known limitation?

Comment: The Font class does not support OpenType.

Comment: If so, how it works in Windows 10 OS?

Comment: There are a *lot* of flavors of this font around, also TrueType versions.